# Redux-form validate on auto-fill

Tags: redux-form

We have a login form using `redux-form` that does not allow the Login button to be pressed until the username and password have been populated.

It works fine, except when Chrome autofills the username/password field we need to trigger a validation of the form so that if both fields are filled in we can enable the Login button.

How would we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it seems there is no way to trigger sync validation through an action creator (see https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/211).

What seems to work for me is calling `handleSubmit` with an empty handler:

```
componentWillMount() {  
  this.props.handleSubmit(() => ({}));
}
```

Although I'm not sure this would work in your scenario with Chrome and autofill. I remember having similar issues there, where the autofilled input would not be marked as changed.